# According to Catholicism can you be saved without being baptised?

Tags: catholicism, soteriology, baptism, catholic-catechism

Is faith through Jesus Christ without baptism enough for salvation? According to the bible, “without faith, it is hard to please God”. If someone at a young age whose been baptised didn’t have faith when they reach maturity, would this cancel out the grace of salvation through baptism? Would this also be the same for those who have faith but without baptism?

Comment: What research have you done in this regard?

Comment: I didn’t do any research. It just came up to my mind. I know some catechism teaching but my mind is arguing about salvation and baptism because if you have already faith but not baptised would this not enough when a person didn’t have a chance to be baptised and died?

Comment: @KayleeA FYI, failing to do any research _is_ a reason for closing/deleting questions on this website.

Comment: @Peter Did you mean it's not a reason? We often downvote unresearches questions, but I don't really remember questions ever being closed for not showing research. (This site does not have the problems of [English.se] in that regard.)

Comment: @curiousdannii hmm, I think it used to be a reason, a long time ago.  Oh well, it's not a rote reason, but it is a reason.   I'm responding to the comment, I think the question is OK. But for kaylee's benefit, it would be good to do some research first before asking questions - especially if they turn into discussions.

Comment: Sorry, I’m still learning about the rules on this site as you know I’m new. I find the rule intimidating if the question in not acceptable to the liking of the reader and you get downvoted. I don’t think there is freedom of speech. I don’t downvote a person just because it’s not up to my standard. Every one is only trying to make contributions whether it’s good or bad. For me I just ignore the bad and move on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is faith through Jesus Christ without baptism enough for salvation?**

Regarding [baptism of desire](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32085), let the ***Catechism of the Catholic Church*** speak for itself:

> [1259](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P3M.HTM) For catechumens who die before their Baptism, their explicit desire to receive it, together with repentance for their sins, and charity, assures them the salvation that they were not able to receive through the sacrament.
>
> [1263](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P3N.HTM) By Baptism all sins are forgiven, original sin and all personal sins, as well as all punishment for sin.65 In those who have been reborn nothing remains that would impede their entry into the Kingdom of God, neither Adam's sin, nor personal sin, nor the consequences of sin, the gravest of which is separation from God.
>
> 1265 Baptism not only purifies from all sins, but also makes the neophyte "a new creature," an adopted son of God, who has become a "partaker of the divine nature,"68 member of Christ and coheir with him, and a temple of the Holy Spirit.

Thus infant who are baptized have been free from original sin and have become a ***new creature*** in the eyes of the Church and of God.

Babies that die after baptism are in heaven and their salvation in not in question:

> [1279](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P3O.HTM) The fruit of Baptism, or baptismal grace, is a rich reality that includes forgiveness of original sin and all personal sins, birth into the new life by which man becomes an adoptive son of the Father, a member of Christ and a temple of the Holy Spirit. By this very fact the person baptized is incorporated into the Church, the Body of Christ, and made a sharer in the priesthood of Christ.
>
> 1280 **Baptism imprints on the soul an indelible spiritual sign, the character, which consecrates the baptized person for Christian worship. Because of the character Baptism cannot be repeated** (cf. DS 1609 and DS 1624).
>
> 1281 Those who die for the faith, those who are catechumens, and all those who, without knowing of the Church but acting under the inspiration of grace, seek God sincerely and strive to fulfill his will, are saved even if they have not been baptized (cf. LG 16).
>
> 1282 Since the earliest times, **Baptism has been administered to children, for it is a grace and a gift of God that does not presuppose any human merit; children are baptized in the faith of the Church. Entry into Christian life gives access to true freedom.**
>
> 1283 With respect to **children who have died without Baptism, the liturgy of the Church invites us to trust in God's mercy and to pray for their salvation.**
>
> 1284 In case of necessity, any person can baptize provided that he have the intention of doing that which the Church does and provided that he pours water on the candidate's head while saying: "I baptize you in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit."

Comment: I noticed Mr. Graham that you left out #1257? "The Lord himself affirms Baptism is necessary for salvation." So I have a question from Acts 10:43-48, it concerns a man named "Cornelius," who was a Roman centurion. Vs43, Of Him/Jesus Christ all the prophets bear witness that through His name receives forgiveness of sins. vs44, While Peter was still speaking these words, the Holy Spirit fell upon all those who were listening to the message. vs45, And all the circumcised believers who had come with Peter were amazed, because (or why?) the gift of the Holy Spirit had been poured out upon the Genti

Comment: So far so good about your Baptism reference but need more to expound the faith in relation to baptism.

Comment: I will accept this answer as it is the best among the rest.

Comment: Kaylee A, I edited my question so it does not involve Ken, it's an open ended questions directed to the Roman Catholic Church. It"s a simple and straight forward question. If it does not meet your approval please let me know.

Comment: @Mr.Bond, you might need to raise it as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

## Baptism is necessary for salvation.

### Scriptural teaching that baptism is, for salvation, a

#### necessity of means

[John 3:5](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=3&l=5#x):

> Jesus answered: Amen, amen I say to thee, unless a man be born again of water and the Holy Ghost, he cannot enter into the kingdom of God.

[Mk. 16:16](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=48&ch=16&l=16-#x):

> He that believeth **and is baptized**, shall be saved: but he that believeth not shall be condemned.

#### necessity of precept

[Mt. 28:19](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=28&l=19-#x):

> Going therefore, teach ye all nations; baptizing them in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Ghost.

### Magisterial teaching

The Council of Trent defined this *de fide* dogma of the necessity of baptism in its [session 7 canon 5](https://ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2/creeds2.v.i.i.v.html#v.i.i.v-p4.23):

> **If anyone shall say that baptism is** optional, that is, **not necessary for salvation: let him be anathema**.
> <sub>Si quis dixerit, baptismum liberum esse, hoc est non necessarium ad salutem, A.S.</sub>

## The types of baptism

1. [Water baptism](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32076)
2. [Baptism of desire](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32085)
3. [Baptism of blood](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32084)

Comment: Does baptisms supersede faith? Or do they weigh of equal importance? I appreciate your great effort in providing reference.

Comment: @KayleeA Faith is required: "[He that believeth \[i.e., has faith\]](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/Holy7Sacraments-Baptism.shtml) and is baptized, shall be saved" ([Mk. 16:16](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=48&ch=16&l=16-#x)).

Comment: @KayleeA To summarize, in Catholicism, sacrament of baptism is valid only with faith.  For infant baptism, the parents's faith suffice. But if you lose your salvation by maturity because of mortal sin, you don't need to be rebaptized but go to sacrament of reconciliation.  Baptism of desire / blood are **exceptions** (for unbaptized person in danger of dying before the proper sacrament can be administered); so only for them the effect of baptism can be acquired without the sacrament, thus the name "of desire" and "of blood" (no water).  The availability of exception doesn't make it optional !

Answer (score 0):

According to Catholicism can one be saved without being water baptized? The Catholic Catechism says,

> Baptism is birth into new life in Christ. In accordance with the Lord's will, it is necessary for salvation. As is the Church herself which we enter by baptism.
>
> [CCC 1277](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/para/1277.htm)

The Apostle Paul makes known the gospel under the influence of the Holy Spirit and the Lord's will the following at:

> Now I make known to you, brethren, the gospel which I preached to you, which also you received, in which also you stand, by which also you are saved, if you hold fast the word which I preached to you, unless you believed in vain. For I delivered to you as of first importance what I also received, that Christ died for our sins according to the Scriptures, and that He was buried, and that He was raised on the third day according to the Scriptures
>
> 1 Corinthians 15:1-4

Since this is the gospel of Jesus Christ whereby one is saved, how is it that water baptism is not mentioned? The catechism (#1277) clearly states it's the Lord's will that water baptism is necessary for salvation.

Comment: This question is asked for from a Catholic perspective and as such should reflect Catholic teachings and not just a half answer. The Church acknowledges exceptions in regards to baptism as the Catechism states.

Comment: No matter how I ask a question it's unsatisfactory. The catechism says water baptism is necessary for salvation and it's the Lord's will. The Apostle Paul at 1 Corinthians 15:1-4.explains the "gospel" and water baptism is not mentioned. Paul even mentions at 1 Corinthians 1:14, "I thank God that I did not baptize any of you etc. I am not Catholic and I also know your church has an answer for everything even if it's outright contrary to Biblical theology. The Bible does not contradict itself and verses that "seem" to contradict themselves can be reconciled. God's word is truth, not opinions.

Comment: Please do not get me wrong your answer is good. It is just not complete. In order to understand the question at hand, one has to truly comprehend the whole body of the question.  Unfortunately, also is the fact that revisions or edit in effect alter the original post. This seems to be happening more so lately.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Graham, I will address the posters question directly in due time.

Comment: @Mr.Bond, it is the Lord’s “will” because Our Lord Himself batized the people. Baptism is to clean our sin for our salvation.


1 Peter 3:21 RHE

21 Whereunto baptism, being of the like form, now saveth you also: not the putting away of the filth of the flesh, but, the examination of a good conscience towards God by the resurrection of Jesus Christ.

John 3:22



John 3:26

26. And they came to John and said to him: Rabbi, he that was with thee beyond the Jordan, to whom thou gavest testimony: behold, he baptizeth and all men come to him.

Comment: @Mr.Bond, how do you received a “gift”? You either accept or reject a gift, yes?Therefore this is an action/work? Even the devil believe but they reject it. It is how we cooperate or respond to this faith to please God, yes? It takes two for this gift/faith to take place I.e. offer and acceptance, without acceptance there is no offer. While baptism, the Lord Himself was baptised so that the water will be purified. Why? So that man will be purified by water in baptism. While faith and baptism are both important for salvation. They are not of equal standing due to their different functionality.

Comment: This is a separate question, please ask it as a question.

Comment: The Church teaching is saying that the institution of Baptism and the Church are necessary for God's plan of salvation--that they are necessary for humanity's salvation, it is not saying that they are required for an individual human. The CCC, the catechism of Trent, and the saints, affirm this.

Comment: I suggest you look up the definition of necrssary. "Required, essential. And the Bible teaches it is not essential because it is considered a work. Read Ephesisns 2:8-9 just for starters. And by the way, RCC teaching is not necessarily Bible teaching.

Comment: @Mr.Bond, bear in mind that Ephesians 2:8-9 is a gospel address to the gentiles in Ephesus part of Greece who are pagans and worship a pagan god. He was preaching “faith” in Jesus and negates their good works mean nothing because they worship the false god. Also the same applies to the self righteous Pharisee who rejected Jesus and therefore their righteousness means nothing.

Comment: Kaylee, you sure are trying hard to make excuses that the words of the Bible don't mean what they say and teach. Here your telling me that Ephesians 2:8-9 is addressed to gentiles in Ephesus part of Greece who are pagans and worship a pagan god. They formally worshiped pagan gods. Now they are saved and Paul is encouraging these new believers.  All of the epistles of the Apostle Paul are written to believers in Jesus Christ. How is it you "missed" such an obvious fact? Please read 2 Timothy 3:16-17. 1 Peter 1:1, "Peter  says in his introduction, "received a faith of the same kind as ours.

Comment: So you think your faith “alone” will save you and your good work has no merit to our Lord? Ok then, so good luck on judgement day. “ I was naked and you clothed me, I was hungry and you fed me. What you did to the least of your brother, you did them to me.”. Oh yeah I get it. You were in Ephesus and heard St. Paul preaching and everything what’s going on. Ok.got you. So good luck again.

Comment: No need for "snide" remarks Kaylee? James 2:17, Even so faith, if it has no works, is dead, being by itself." The Apostle Paul says were saved by grace through faith, and not by works. So how do we reconcile this "apparent" contradiction? Read closely James words, "Even so faith, if it has no works is dead." James was "NOT" teaching that saving faith is earned by good works, but that true faith RESULTS IN GODLY ACTION OF GOOD WORKS. A faith which does not result in a change in a believer's life is not truly faith. James 2:14. Your works prove your faith and we are to be a blessing to others.